# My Maytag Atlantis washer spins but doesn't agitate

Tags: washer

I have a Maytag Atlantis washer and I replaced the water pump because it was seized up and the belt couldn't turn it. Before I turned it on to test it, the center pulley spins easily in one direction and gave me resistance in the other direction but after testing it, it spins easily in both directions and now I hear a loud banging noise when it seems to try to agitate. Do I need to replace the center pulley or is it something else?

UPDATE: The model number is MAV6451AWW

Comment: What's the model number on your washer?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I updated my question to show the model number